# Paperclip: Assign an image programmatically and set its name

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Using Paperclip, I want to grab an image from a URL like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

user.photo = open(url)
```

The problem is that I then wind up with a filename like 'open-uri20110915-4852-1o7k5uw'. Is there any way I can change the filename on user.photo?

As an added twist, Paperclip is storing my files on S3, so it'd be even better if I could set the filename I want in the initial assignment, so images get uploaded to the right S3 key. Something like this:

```
user.photo = open(url), :filename => URI.parse(url).path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the filename back to your instance via:

```
 photo.instance_write(:file_name, new_file_name)
```

So if your source URL is like:

```
 http://example.com/foo.jpg
```

You can first parse the name from the URL (to get `foo.jpg`) and then write it back to the instance using the above `instance_write` method.

Comment: And I do this after assigning the `open(url)` to photo? I tried this with an existing user whose photo is already on S3. Now `u.photo_file_name` returns the new name, but `u.photo(:original)` still has the old S3 url, as well as `u.photo.path`. And the file on S3 didn't move.

Comment: If the image is existing you might have to call "photo.reprocess!" to have Paperclip update your storage backend (S3). Otherwise, the above works prior to your first save and should save it correctly to S3 when eventually the save does happen

Comment: Note that sometimes paperclip does change the filename to replace characters, so whatever filename you set must match those rules otherwise paperclip can lose it.

Answer (score 5):

```
io = open(url)
def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
```

This will set the filename to the filename in the url.

Comment: I hit this problem again recently and had to adopt something more like this approach this time. Here is a blog post about it: http://www.illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2013/06/paperclip-with-server-side-files/